# Affect a function of -webkit-transform in a -webkit-animation without affecting other -webkit-transform functions applied to the target element?

Tags: animation, css, webkit

I want to animate the -webkit-transform: rotateX() of elements while allowing the elements to keep their -webkit-transform: rotate() property intact. Consider the following code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg); }
}

.target {
    -webkit-animation: anim .5s infinite alternate linear;
}

.target.one {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.target.two {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

In this scenario, targets one and two start rotated correctly, but their rotation gets overridden when the animation applies its -webkit-transform: rotateX()

How can I animate only the rotateX function of -webkit-transform?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use a wrapper div that has the base transforms (-45/45) applied to it, with the animation class applied to the wrapped div.